# Custom Interceptor not being registered

Tags: spring-boot

All,

I am attempting to register a custom interceptor, for a SOAP based, web service, using the code I have pasted below.

I do not see, in my logs, any evidence where either of these classes is being called.

I would appreciate any ideas anyone has as to how to troubleshoot this issue.

Thanks,
snappersdad

```
public class InquiryServiceInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

     private static Logger rollingFileLogger = LogManager.getLogger(InquiryServiceInterceptor.class);

     @Override
     public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

         rollingFileLogger.debug("Entered preHandle");

         return true;
     }

     @Override
     public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

         rollingFileLogger.debug("Entered postHandle");
     }

     @Override
     public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception exception) throws Exception {

         rollingFileLogger.debug("Entered afterCompletion");

     }

}

@Component
public class InquiryServiceInterceptorAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static Logger rollingFileLogger = LogManager.getLogger(InquiryServiceInterceptorAppConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    InquiryServiceInterceptor inquiryServiceInterceptor;

     @Override
     public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

         rollingFileLogger.debug("Adding interceptor 'inquiryServiceInterceptor'...");

         registry.addInterceptor(inquiryServiceInterceptor);

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found the solution!

1) Add the following to the spring-ws-servlet.xml file

```
<!-- Intercept all requests -->
<sws:interceptors>
    <bean class="xxx.xxxxxxx.xxx.xxx.InquiryServiceInterceptor"/>
</sws:interceptors>
```

See: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-ws/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/ 5.5.2 Intercepting requests - the EndpointInterceptor interface for more details

2) Delete attempt to add the interceptor via Java class, (see above) InquiryServiceInterceptorAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

3) Update the interceptor class.  Please see new version (NOTE: Implementing the EndpointInterceptor)

````
public class InquiryServiceInterceptor implements EndpointInterceptor  {

     private static Logger rollingFileLogger = LogManager.getLogger(InquiryServiceInterceptor.class);


     @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {

         rollingFileLogger.debug("Entered handleRequest");

         return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {

        rollingFileLogger.debug("Entered handleResponse");

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {

        rollingFileLogger.debug("Entered handleFault");

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint, Exception ex) throws Exception {

        rollingFileLogger.debug("Entered afterCompletion");

    }

}```
````